# Aligning Text And Arrow (With Google Fonts)

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align both the text and the right arrow (with Google fonts) in the middle of the div but no matter what I tried, I could not succeed. How can they be aligned?

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">

<div style="width:300px; background-color:#ADD8E6; padding:0.5rem 1rem; text-align:center;display:inline-block;">
<div style="float:right;">
<span class="material-icons" style=" font-size:2rem;">&#xe315;</span>
</div>

<div style="padding-left:20px; padding-right:20px;">
Some Text
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either set `margin-top: 7px` on the text element, or preferably, set a `line-height` equal to the height of the container (in this case, 36px), minus a few pixels to counter the height of the icon. In this example, I've gone with 34px:

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">

<div style="width:300px; background-color:#ADD8E6; padding:0.5rem 1rem; text-align:center;display:inline-block;">
<div style="float:right;">
<span class="material-icons" style=" font-size:2rem;">&#xe315;</span>
</div>

<div style="padding-left:20px; padding-right:20px; line-height: 34px;">
Some Text
</div>

</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use absolute positioning on the arrow, and `top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%);` to center it vertically.

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<div style="width:300px; background-color:#ADD8E6; padding:0.5rem 1rem; text-align:center;display:inline-block; position: relative;">
  <span class="material-icons" style=" font-size:2rem; position: absolute; top: 50%; right: 1rem; transform: translateY(-50%);">&#xe315;</span>
  <div>
    Some Text
  </div>
</div>
```